# Под зонтиком — под зонтом

Tags: фонетика

Если мы говорим "под зОнтиком", то как ставить ударение с случае "зонта": "под зонтОм" или "под зОнтом"?

Comment: Аналогично : под мостиком и под мостом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под зонтОм. 
Как-то связывать место ударания двух форм и общность корневого морфа в подобных случаях не стоит. Тут важнее число слогов, хотя общих правил все равно нет.